# I can't add posted data to database sent from javascript where executed in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have problem with my code.

In this code I am sending some data to another server.

```
fetch("https://example.com/test.php", {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',

  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
"isim": lastPlayersTouched[0].name,
"sure": getTime(scores)
  })

});
```

And here I have database connection:

```
<?php 

try {

    $db=new PDO("mysql:localhost;dbname=test1_evet;charset=utf8",'test1_evet','N#rK%*?PkTki');
    //echo "ok";

} 

catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

?>
```

And the final part here I am trying to add posted things to add my database:

```
<?php 
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); 
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
    header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 1000');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token , Authorization');

require_once 'baglan.php';

// if (isset($_POST)) {

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
  $arr = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);

    $kaydet=$db->prepare("INSERT into test SET
        isim=:isim,
        sure=:sure
        ");

    $insert=$kaydet->execute(array(

        // 'isim' => $_POST['isim'],
        'isim' => $arr['isim'],
        // 'sure' => $_POST['sure']
        'sure' => $arr['sure']

    ));

}

// }

?>
```

But the problem is,  I can send data from another server to my current server with 200 OK code. But PHP doesn't add things I've sent to database. I mean not inserting to database. Can someone help me on that? I will be very happy if you guys help me.

Any fix?

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton - seems like valid syntax to me

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton Thank you so much for the help. But this I mean current code I can send data with 200 ok code. When I change the wrong syntax to correct syntax code you've sent, I am getting this error:

Comment: Fetch API cannot load https://www.example.com/islem.php. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://www.haxball.com' is therefore not allowed access. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

In the console ^^

Comment: @RamRaider Interesting, never seen that syntax before but you do appear to be correct.

Comment: @user12842890 I recently saw that error in my own project, it was because the part of my site that was trying to contact the API was being called in an AJAX request which was not allowed by the server I was connecting to.

Comment: The preflight request indicates the OPTIONS request sent by the browser for the legitimacy of the target host. Most probably the web server fails to reply with necessary access control headers to that OPTIONS request.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton I can send a request to Discord api with fetch. I don't think I have some block to make requests. The problem is even I set cors to enabled, it still says me "no access controll allow origin header is presented on the requested source. Idk why

Comment: @user "_**on the requested source**_"; as in not your site, but the resource your site is requesting. It could be many things, in my case I got this error (From the Spotify API) when trying to refresh my access token (which requires a page redirect).

Comment: so - are you saying that the POST request never even reaches the PHP code because of the lack of the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header?

Comment: @RamRaider yes exactly

Comment: but the problem is, today I've sent requests with 200 ok code. So I don't think there is any block in both side. I don't know why that is happening now.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/nm6ccm look, I can send fetch request to discord api, but not to my server. And I don't think Discord api is manually allowed. Because other people sending fetch requests to their server but I can't.

Comment: @RamRaider  ^^^ check the screenshot

Comment: is the target url `http` or `https`?

Comment: @RamRaider https

Comment: so, the javascript `fetch` code is correct other than the URL? The PHP code is also correct and as being used now on your site?IE: We are looking at virtually the exact code that is giving errors - is that correct?

Comment: 1- Javascript code runs in another server, php code runs in another server.

Comment: 2- Yes all of these codes is running now on my server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
fetch("https://example.com/test.php", {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    mode: 'cors',
    body: JSON.stringify({
        'isim': lastPlayersTouched[0].name,
        'sure': getTime(scores)
    })
});
```

database connection (host parameter missing)

```
$db=new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test1_evet;charset=utf8",'test1_evet','N#rK%*?PkTki');
```

Access-Control-Allow-Headers (xhr header missing)

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token , Authorization, X-Requested-With');
```